# Seekbar in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, seekbar, android-seekbar

I came across a piece of code,now I am stuck with it.

```
        SeekBar volumeControl=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volumeSeekBar);
        volumeControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,progress,0 );


            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

Here I know that `volumeControl` is a variable of type SeekBar. In the second line of code volume control is set with a function `setOnSeekBarChangeListener`. I am unable to understand what's written inside the brackets of `setOnSeekBarChangeListener`. Can anyone please explain it in detail. I am just introduced to java and don't have much knowledge

Comment: the OnSeekBarChangeListener is an example of an anonymous class. take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html. You can also look at the docs for Seek bar https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar

Answer (score 1):

This is a small piece of code to control volume using a seek bar.
Inside the brackets of `onSeekBarChangeListener`, we declare a new `SeekBar.onSeekBarChangeListener` which implements three methods :

1. `onProgressChanged` : This basically tracks the change in the seek bar and then sets the volume according to the amount of change.
2. `onStartTrackingTouch` : This methods contains the code which should be executed when the touch gesture starts.
3. `onStopTrackingTouch`:
   This method contains the code which should be executed which the touch gesture stops.